# qlist with custom class unable to append

Tags: c++, macos, qt5

I've seen other questions on here, but they deal with pointers, or with qobject derived classes, so they didn't seem relevant.

I am trying to append values into a qlist of custom classes, here is the class

```
class matchPair
{
public:
    matchPair(int a=0, int b=0)
        : m_a(a)
        , m_b(b)
    {}
    int a() const { return m_a; }
    int b() const { return m_b; }

    bool operator<(const matchPair &rhs) const { return m_a < rhs.a(); }
//    matchPair& operator=(const matchPair& other) const;

private:
    int m_a;
    int m_b;
};

class videodup
{
public:
    videodup(QString vid = "", int m_a = 0, int m_b = 0);
    ~videodup() {}
    QString video;
    bool operator==(const QString &str) const { return video == str; }
//  videodup& operator=(QString vid, int m_a, int m_b);
    QList<matchPair> matches;
};

struct frm
{
    QString file;
    int position;
    cv::Mat descriptors;
    QList<videodup> videomatches;
};
QList<frm> frames;
```

and the line that fails is:

```
frame.videomatches.at( frame.videomatches.indexOf(vid) ).matches.append(pair);
```

the error I get is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5.1_2/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qlist.h:191: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const QList<matchPair>', but method is not marked const
    void append(const T &t);
         ^
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now you haven't specified the type of `frame` and how it is created. There is a `const` somewhere, that's for sure.

Comment: For future readers, my above comment is wrong, the trick is in the `QList<videodup>::at()` method. The information provided is enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to append a value to a `const QList<T>`, which means your `QList<T>` is constant, i.e. non-mutable. Look closely, the error reads `this has type const QList<matchPair>`, and you can only call `const` methods on a `const` object, while `append()` obviously is not `const` both syntactically and semantically. Fix the `QList<matchPair>` to not be `const`.

Edit 2:

Having looked closer at the code, here is the culprit, indeed:

```
frame.videomatches.at( frame.videomatches.indexOf(vid) ).matches.append(pair);
                   ^^
```

`QList<T>::at()` returns `const T&`, which leads to the problem I've described above. Use `QList<T>::operator[]()` insdead,which has overloads that return both a `const T` and `T` values.

Edit:

However, which compiler brand and version is this? I can't reproduce this error message in g++ by calling a non-`const` method on a `const` class object, both templated and non-templated (I am getting an error, but it's worded differently).

Comment: qt creator 3.6.0 on qt5.5

Comment: Ok, but this is the Qt library version, not the compiler itself!

Comment: gcc Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0

Comment: Output of `g++ --version`?

Comment: g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: Anyway, try my suggestion in the answer above!

Comment: I didn't declare it const though. I will update question with all the type declarations and the line that is faliing

Comment: Post the line where you call `QList<matchPair>::append()`!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102816/discussion-between-iksemyonov-and-neal).

Comment: Neal, follow the link to join the chat. Prolonged discussion are not welcome in the comments.